# Windows Authentication for Postman Restsharp

Tags: postman, windows-authentication, restsharp, ntlm-authentication

Currently,

I using the Postman Restsharp to retrieve the JWT token in **iphone Safari** mobile.

May I ask about how to add the Windows authentication?

I had try the method as below, but I can't retrieve the response data.

But its work at Company Laptop.

```
var client = new RestClient("https://mvponduty.com/XChange_App_Api/api/auth/authenticate");
client.Timeout = -1;
var request = new RestRequest(Method.GET);
request.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
request.AddHeader("Content-Type", " application/json; charset=utf-8");
request.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", " *");
request.AddHeader("Cache-Control", " no-cache");
request.AddHeader("Pragma", " no-cache");
request.AddHeader("Cookie", ".AspNetCore.Session=CfDJ8AoxL%2BrAgZtDtnzh7ZplJfx4moiRGYT4rFtA6zp%2B1d8CAQ4D%2FZary6IvN%2Ftjm7wl2Ke992wbhnP7cmv3q7ba0%2BQoZKHuT%2B2FyJzIAjaJFH2GX0ZFiz1nHdSLyGhPMrG4KCNXZ94u79I7DHKjVAxcREfISUxxrFnxib0Aw1Q4yNQw");
request.AddParameter(" application/json; charset=utf-8", "",  ParameterType.RequestBody);
IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
Console.WriteLine(response.Content);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use another method to generate JWT Token.

```
  string key = "iNivDmHLpUA223sqsfhqGbMRdRj1PVkH";

            // Create Security key  using private key above:
            // not that latest version of JWT using Microsoft namespace instead of System
            var securityKey = new Microsoft
               .IdentityModel.Tokens.SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(key));

            // Also note that securityKey length should be >256b
            // so you have to make sure that your private key has a proper length
            //
            var credentials = new Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.SigningCredentials
                              (securityKey, SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256Signature);

            //  Finally create a Token
            var header = new JwtHeader(credentials);

            //Some PayLoad that contain information about the  customer
            var payload = new JwtPayload
           {
                { "sub", "hello "},
                { "scope", "http://dummy.com/"},
};

     
            var secToken = new JwtSecurityToken(header, payload);
            var handler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();

            // Token to String so you can use it in your client
            var tokenString = handler.WriteToken(secToken);

          

            Console.WriteLine(tokenString);
```